# Google Chrome could not connect to localhost

Tags: macos, google-chrome, apache

I am using OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.4.  I tried the steps in [Installing Apache, PHP, and MySQL on Mac OS X](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/10/install-apache-php-mysql-mac-os-x/) to setup my dev environment, but I am not able to open the virtualhost I created – or `localhost` for that matter.

cURL gives me this error:

> curl: (7) couldn't connect to host

For those who are interested, here's my `httpd-vhosts.conf` file,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/AnkurKaushal/Documents/workspace/dev"
    ServerName ankur.local
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/ankur.local-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/ankur.local-access_log" common

    <Directory "/Users/AnkurKaushal/Documents/workspace/dev">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow, deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and my `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
127.0.0.1       ankur.local
```

What might I be missing here?

Comment: Okay I fixed my own question, those who are having any issues like this. Just do sudo apachectl -t, that will help you fixing any issue your having with Apache configuration.

In my case, it was just a simple space in httpd-vhosts.conf file that was causing the issue.

Comment: Great job, to help us managing this place please make it in a answer so it can be marked as completed.

Answer (score 1):

Just do `sudo apachectl -t`, that will help you fixing any issue your having with Apache configuration.

In that case, it was just a simple space in `httpd-vhosts.conf` file that was causing the issue.